# How does SO get images in its badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, images, design

How did Stack Overflow insert images into its badges? I don't know what you would have to change in a database to have it show HTML.

Comment: BTW, StackOverflow uses SQL Server, *not* MySQL

Comment: Hopefully you don't have to change _anything_ in your database to update your UI...

Answer (score 3):

That image came from [gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/).